# How to traverse loop in Go and print out every third element

Tags: for-loop, go

I know to traverse through a list, i would do the following:

```
for e := alist.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
       fmt.Println(e.Value) 
   }
```

However, I would like to print out every third element. In other langauges, i would increment the index like e += 3. How do I do that with Go?

Comment: The problem is not about Go per se, you are using an iterator with `.Next` which in any other languages will move the cursor to the next item.
If you really want to skip a certain number of elements you will need to keep track of the count of elements you have seen so far using a variable and use a check in the loop

Comment: Or, alternatively, invoke `e.Next()` three times in the loop, taking care not to use `.Next()` on a nil `e`, perhaps by defining an `Advance` function (or see Howard's update with `NextByCount`, which is what I was thinking of here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List is a doubly linked list which doesn't allow to seek or jump by a specific count. My workaround is this:

```
i := 0
for e := alist.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
    if i % 3 == 0 {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }

    i++
}
```

Or a new function for code reuse (with @torek's comment, it becomes simpler):

```
func NextByCount(el *list.Element, count int) *list.Element {
    for ; el != nil && count > 0; count-- {
        el = el.Next()
    }

    return el
}
```

Then loop it like:

```
for e := alist.Front(); e != nil; e = NextByCount(e, 3) {
    fmt.Println(e.Value)
}
```

Comment: I'd allow `NextByCount` (or `Advance`) to take a nil argument and return nil: `for ; el != nil && count > 0; count--) { el = el.Next() } return el`

Comment: Yeah, it looks better. 

Comment: just a note: I would say the second way is better than the first one, as it is cleaner, more robust, and more performant.